# Pivot table to find max, min, avg temp in large data set

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 6 years of data, temperature recorded in 15 min increments. I'd like to find the max, min, avg by month (so max temp from all januarys, max from all feb. etc.) When I plot the pivot table I get "0" in the value field.  I plot Month_2 as the row and Value as the "value".

[image: E]

Comment: I can add more of my data-but perhaps this is a simple answer that I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green triangles in the VALUE column indicate that the numbers are stored as text, so they cannot be processed by PIVOT. To convert them back to numbers, you have to select the entire column except the heading, click on yellow exclamation mark and then choose `Convert to number` .

[image]